# Deshabilitar refresco de pantalla hasta fin de operacion

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Actualmente tengo un codigo que me refresca unas pantallas MdiCildren, el caso es que al hacer esto visualmente queda un poco feo hasta que termina, asi que necesito saber si es posible y como hacer que no se pinte nada en la pantalla hasta llegado un punto y que se refreque la pantalla en ese momento

mezclando codigo y seudocodigo seria algo asi

```
        noRefrescar();
        foreach( Form f in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        Refrescar();
```

Gracias.

Comment: has probado con `this.SuspendLayout()` y `this.ResumeLayout(true)` ?

Comment: Aparte de lo que te sugiere @lois6b, echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487757/579895) que utiliza mensajes de windows para deshabilitar el redibujado de los controles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[En la documentacion de C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) puedes ver los metodos `SuspendLayout` y `ResumeLayout` que hacen justo lo que necesitas:

```
this.SuspendLayout();
foreach( Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
this.ResumeLayout(true);
```

Hay otras maneras, utilizando `Workers` en otros hilos que te envien un `ready` cuando lo que necesitas detectar ha acabado pero para tu caso puntual no es necesario tanta complicación.

Answer (score 1):

Podría utilizar los métodos `SuspendLayout` y `ResumeLayout`, pero en el caso que no funcionen podría implementar estos dos métodos:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr wnd, int msg, bool param, int lparam);

 public static int WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B;

 //Suspende el Redibujo del control
 public static void SuspendDrawing(IntPtr handle)
 {
    SendMessage(handle,WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
 }

 //Habilita el redibujo del control
 public static void ResumeDrawing(IntPtr handle)
 {
     SendMessage(handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
 }
```

Lo puede implementar de la siguiente manera:

```
SuspendDrawing(this.Handle);
foreach( Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
     f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
ResumeDrawing(this.Handle);
this.Refresh();
this.Update();
```

**NOTA:** Por ninguna razón debe olvida llamar el método `ResumeDrawing`, así podría evitar cualquier problema de dibujo del objeto.